# How to do unit testing in kdb language?

Tags: unit-testing, kdb

Has anyone has done kdb unit testing before? I have no idea how I should do unit testing. I am confused about time store unit testing as well.

I will load my script, Qunit script and test script. However, I am not sure how to write the test code for queries. What should I write for expected result?

Comment: I found several results simply from Google, including one from "timestored.com", which I imagine is related to the "time store unit testing" you mentioned. That particular link has an introduction and examples - http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-regression-unit-tests. Please ask specific questions, with sample code and expected results, as well as what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

QUnit a unit testing framework for kdb is documented here:
http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/kdb-regression-unit-tests

With the source code being available here:
https://github.com/timeseries/kdb/tree/master/qunit

If you have any specific questions, just ask.

Comment: Hi Ryan, so I will load my own code, test cod and qunit code. But I would like to know how I can write test codes to test queries?

Comment: Use the setup and teardown functionality to create tables, that the queries are then ran against. Compare the results with the expected.